# Embedding Python in C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I've been trying to run a Python 3 script through C using code the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html) provided.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyLong_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

test.py:

```
def multiply(a,b):
    print("Will compute", a, "times", b)
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

I enter into the console:

```
./pytest test multiply 3 4
```

and I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'multiply'
Cannot find function "multiply"
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10; I figured this was relevant because the documentation appeared to be addressing Windows. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten (or rather, were never told) that [the current/script/executable directory is not added to `sys.path` when embedding the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917645/embedding-python-in-c-having-problems-importin-local-modules), so you've found some completely different module called "test" and are importing that instead.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I'll keep this in mind in the future. Since I still have your attention, I've renamed the file to "qwe.py" and now I get ImportError: No module named 'qwe'
Failed to load "qwe"

Comment: Never mind I'm headed towards the right direction now. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1610810: The problem isn't that it found some other module instead of yours, it's that it isn't capable of finding yours in the first place.

Comment: I figured that. I tried making it reachable using PySys_SetPath(PyBytes_FromString("/home/frosty/NetBeansProjects/pyTest/")); , but no luck. Is there documentation I can just dive into?

Comment: @user1610810: No, there is none. You can manipulate `sys.path` as you would any other list though.

Comment: Took me a while but I got it. Thanks for the help.